# How to restrict special symbols like % in textbox in wpf?

Tags: wpf, textbox, validation

I would like to develop a textbox which restricts special symbols like %. I used textbox's keydown event to restrict '%' . I already used the code as

```
if(Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift && e.key == key.D5)    
{    
    e.handle=true;    
    return;    
}
```

when i implement this in mvvm architecture, I got problem with the dependency property that recognizes only shift as one key and D5 as another when I converted systemkey into string format.

How can I recognize % symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can listen to the PreviewTextInput event instead of the KeyDownEvent :

```
myTextBox.PreviewTextInput += PreviewTextInputHandler;
```

and then:

```
private void PreviewTextInputHandler(Object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !AreAllValidChars(e.Text);
}
```

this is one such function I use in my App, you would have to tweak it a bit to test the right caracters, but this you know how to do.

as for getting the % caracter, well you just have to write something like:

```
if (e.Text == '%') ...;
```